# Odoo from email_template class method is called twice

Tags: python, python-2.7, jinja2, odoo, odoo-9

I am trying send email with data which I am getting from the `get_record_ids` method. The problem is that `get_record_ids` sometimes called twice, sometimes once and I have no idea why.

email_template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="email_template_test" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">test</field>
            <field name="email_from">xxx@mail.com</field>
            <field name="email_to">xxl@mail.com</field>
            <field name="subject">test</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="test.model_test"/>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
            <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[
                <p>Hi,</p>This is simple test <br><br>

                <table width="771" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" border="1" height="73">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>Number</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Result</td>
            </tr>
            % if object.get_record_ids():
                % for values in object.get_record_ids()
                <tr>
                        <td>${values['number']}</td>
                        <td>${values['name']}</td>
                        <td>${values['result']}</td>
                </tr>
                % endfor
                % endif
                </tbody></table><br>
        ]]></field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

get_record_ids method

```
@api.model
def get_record_ids(self):
       ticket_ids = self.env['stock.location'].search([('usage','=','view')], limit=5)
       records=[]
       for ticket_id in ticket_ids:
           tickets={}
           result = ticket_id.result
       ticket_id.result_difference = ticket_id.last_month_result - result
       ticket_id.last_month_result = result
       if ticket_id.result_difference != 0 and ticket_id:
       tickets['number'] = ticket_id.number
       tickets['name'] = ticket_id.name
       tickets['result'] = ticket_id.result
               records.append(tickets)
       return records
```

And:

```
@api.model
def get_data(self):
res_id = 2
    template = self.env.ref('test.email_template_test')
    self.env['mail.template'].browse(template.id).send_mail(res_id, force_send=True)
```

`ticket_id.result` is the computed value.

Comment: How do you call this email to be sent? Button? Or what?

Comment: I updated my question. I have cron job which runs everyday and calls get_data method.

Comment: Just wondering: Why do you call `browse()` in your last line? `template.send_mail(res_id, force_send=True)` would be enough.

Comment: @CZoellner I fixed it but situation is still the same. I don't know what can cause the problem... Is it method or template..

Comment: It's difficult to say. Just debug into the method and try to find it out ;-)